# seedbox with video streaming for linux?

Tags: ubuntu, bittorrent

I have a linux server where I wish I could access via web client and be able to download videos with a magnet link and then stream it through vlc or html5 video, does such thing exists?

Answer (score 1):

Using this [seedbox from scratch](https://github.com/Notos/seedbox-from-scratch) script I was able to setup a web-based interface on my headless server where I could download files, with a little tinkering I was also able to install [Plex](https://plex.tv/) which is an excellent piece of software with apps for everything. Depending on how you want to use it, it may require you paying a subscription, but it's the best piece of software I have used for such a thing. It transcodes, organizes, and streams to just about anything (WebBrowser,Roku,XBone,Android,IOS... you name it). I use this just like you mention with mag-links. This mag-link support, as well as RSS support allows me to autodownload using ShowRSS (Google that one, sorry I dont have enough rep to post more than 2 links) the shows that I watch weekly, and also makes it easy to manually add other things like movies, or extra shows that I simply download all at once.

Answer (score 0):

yes, such thing exists. have a look at https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc
Kodi (formerly known as XBMC) is a free and open source (GPL) software media center for playing videos, music, etc. You can use it with some torrent addons, e.g. http://addons.kodi.tv/show/plugin.program.utorrent/
here is the Linux guide
http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux